# perl update query errors

Tags: bash, shell, perl

i want to execute an update query with a int value in a column but not work :

```
my $t = 9;
my $query4 = $db2->prepare("UPDATE worldmap_table SET severity = $t, name = ? WHERE HOST = ?");


$query3->execute;

#############marche pas
while (my @row2 = $query3->fetchrow_array) {
    $query4->execute($row2[2], $row2[1], $row2[0]);
    print "$row2[2], $row2[1], $row2[0] \n";
}
```

error message :

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 3 bind variables when 2 are needed at /srv/test.pl 
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 3 bind variables when 2 are needed at /srv/test.pl
```

Comment: `SET severity = $t` should (probably) be `SET severity = ?`. Voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: The diagnostic messages are pretty self-explanatory.  You only have two slots in your prepared query, but you are giving three variables in the execution. Reduce the number of variables to the two you are really interested on.

Comment: i want put 9 in severity column